# What Is The SQL To Do This?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table with two columns, the CustomerID and the Login Date/Time when they logged in.  Effectively, every time they log in, their Customer ID and the Login Date/Time gets inserted into this table.

What is the most efficient SQL to give me a list of not only the Customer ID, but the count of how many times they have logged in during the last 30 days, 60 days, and 90 days?

Comment: What is your _metric_ for "most efficient"? Fewest characters in the query? Lowest number of physical reads? Least effort on your part?

Answer (score 5):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customerid,
       sum(case when logindatetime >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_30,
       sum(case when logindatetime >= dateadd(day, -60, getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_60,
       sum(case when logindatetime >= dateadd(day, -90, getdate()) then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_90
from logins
where logindatetime >= dateadd(day, -90, getdate())
group by customerid;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is functionally identical to Gordon's answer, but I'd already started typing so I figure I'll finish posting it. Minor differences include:

1. Included some sample data
2. Used `IIF` function (SQL Server 2012+ only; Syntactic sugar for `case when <predicate> then <value> end`)
3. Encapsulated the datediff into a column so as not to have to rewrite it for each expression

Code:

```
with src (CustId, LoginDt) as
(
    select 1, getdate() - 89 union all
    select 2, getdate() - 90 union all
    select 2, getdate() - 59 union all
    select 3, getdate() - 61 union all
    select 3, getdate() - 31 union all
    select 3, getdate() - 30 union all
    select 3, getdate() - 29 union all
    select 3, getdate() union all
    select 4, getdate() - 12
), logins as
(
    select CustId, LoginDt, DaysSinceLastLogin = datediff(day, getdate(), LoginDt)
    from src
)
select 
    CustId,
    LastLogin = max(loginDt),
    Last30 = sum(iif(DaysSinceLastLogin >= -30, 1, 0)),
    Last60 = sum(iif(DaysSinceLastLogin >= -30, 1, 0)),
    Last90 = sum(iif(DaysSinceLastLogin >= -90, 1, 0))       
from logins
where LoginDt >= dateadd(day, -90, getdate())
group by CustId
```